# How can I merge the data files with matching the data at Windows batch

Tags: batch-file, merge

I'm sorry but I'm not good at Windows batch.

I want to merge two or more files with matching by key value. Those files has different numbers of the lines.

For example:

File_A.txt

```
Time, D1, D2
1.1, 11, 12
1.2, 21, 22
1.3, 31, 32
1.4, 41, 42
1.5, 51, 52
```

File_B.txt

```
Time, D3, D4
1.1, 13, 14
1.3, 33, 34
1.4, 43, 44
```

File_C.txt

```
Time, D5, D6
1.2, 25, 26
1.4, 45, 46
1.5, 55, 56
```

I want to get:

Merged.txt

```
Time, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6
1.1, 11, 12, 13, 14
1.2, 21, 22,   ,   , 25, 26
1.3, 31, 32, 33, 34
1.4, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46
1.5, 51, 52,   ,   , 55, 56
```

If I make it at C / C++, then it will be easy, but because of my situation, I have to make it at Windows batch, and I cannot imagenate how I have to do.

Please give your favor.

Comment: You need to do some research and try it on your own. Otherwise this question appears to be a code/script request, which is clearly off-topic here. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: Does `File_A.txt` always contain all possible `Time` values?

Comment: Sorry, Sir. I'm also don't like to ask something without search ownself,
and actually, I already searched several hours but I cannot find the answer which suitable for me, or make too much long code.

Yes, File_A.txt contains the all values of the Time.

Comment: Then write the pseudo code in C and try to translate it to batch and ask about the problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution process *all files* named `File_*.txt` in current directory and assume that the "master file" (the one with all keys) is *the first file*.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "keys="
for %%f in (File_*.txt) do (
   if not defined keys (
      for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%%f") do (
         set "line[%%a]=%%a,%%b"
         set "keys=!keys! %%a"
      )
   ) else (
      set "rest=!keys!"
      for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%%f") do (
         set "line[%%a]=!line[%%a]!,%%b"
         set "rest=!rest: %%a=!"
      )
      for %%k in (!rest!) do set "line[%%k]=!line[%%k]!,   ,   "
   )
)
(for %%k in (%keys%) do echo !line[%%k]!) > Merged.txt
```

Using your three example files as input, this is the output:

```
Time, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6
1.1, 11, 12, 13, 14,   ,
1.2, 21, 22,   ,   , 25, 26
1.3, 31, 32, 33, 34,   ,
1.4, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46
1.5, 51, 52,   ,   , 55, 56
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch script that should do what you want, although it is not very efficient on large files. It relies on the fact that all the files have got the same number of columns (three in our situation), and that the first file provided has got all possible values in its first column. Supposing the script is saved as `merge.bat`, you need to provide the files to merge as command line arguments, like:

```cmd
merge.bat "File_A.txt" "File_B.txt" "File_C.txt"
```

The result file will always be `Merged.txt` in the current working directory. So here is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SEPAR=, "
set "_FILL=%_SEPAR%  %_SEPAR%  "
set "_RESULT=Merged.txt"

set "FIRST=#"
for %%A in (%*) do (
    if defined FIRST (
        > nul copy /Y "%%~nxA" "%_RESULT%"
        set "FIRST="
    ) else (
        > "%_RESULT%.tmp" (
            for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%F in ("%_RESULT%") do (
                set "FLAG=" & set "LINE=%%F"
                for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("%%~A") do (
                    for /F "eol=%_SEPAR:~,1% delims=%_SEPAR%" %%E in ("%%F") do (
                        for /F "tokens=1* eol=%_SEPAR:~,1% delims=%_SEPAR%" %%J in ("%%I") do (
                            if "%%E"=="%%J" set "STR=%%K" & set "FLAG=#"
                        )
                    )
                )
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                if defined FLAG (
                    echo(!LINE!%_SEPAR%!STR!
                ) else (
                    echo(!LINE!%_FILL%
                )
                endlocal
            )
        )
        > nul move /Y "%_RESULT%.tmp" "%_RESULT%"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

With your sample files as input, the output in `Merged.txt` is going to be this:

> ```cmd
> Time, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6
> 1.1, 11, 12, 13, 14,   ,   
> 1.2, 21, 22,   ,   , 25, 26
> 1.3, 31, 32, 33, 34,   ,   
> 1.4, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46
> 1.5, 51, 52,   ,   , 55, 56
> ```

---

Here is an alternative batch script. In contrast to the other one, the first file is no longer expected to contain all possible values in its first column. This is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SEPAR=, "
set "_FILL=%_SEPAR%  %_SEPAR%  "
set "_RESULT=Merged.txt"

for /F "delims==" %%E in ('set "$" 2^> nul') do set "%%E="
set /A "INDEX=0"
for %%A in (%*) do (
    for /F "usebackq eol=%_SEPAR:~,1% delims=%_SEPAR%" %%E in ("%%~A") do (
        call set "NUMBER=000000000000%%INDEX%%"
        if not defined $[%%E] call set "$[%%E]=%%NUMBER:~-12%%%_SEPAR%%%E"
        set /A "INDEX+=1"
    )
)
> "%_RESULT%.tmp" (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%E in ('set "$"') do @(
        echo(%%F
    )
)
> "%_RESULT%" (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=%_SEPAR%" %%E in ('sort "%_RESULT%.tmp"') do @(
        echo(%%F
    )
)
del "%_RESULT%.tmp"
for %%A in (%*) do (
    > "%_RESULT%.tmp" (
        for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%F in ("%_RESULT%") do (
            set "FLAG=" & set "LINE=%%F"
            for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("%%~A") do (
                for /F "eol=%_SEPAR:~,1% delims=%_SEPAR%" %%E in ("%%F") do (
                    for /F "tokens=1* eol=%_SEPAR:~,1% delims=%_SEPAR%" %%J in ("%%I") do (
                        if "%%E"=="%%J" set "STR=%%K" & set "FLAG=#"
                    )
                )
            )
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if defined FLAG (
                echo(!LINE!%_SEPAR%!STR!
            ) else (
                echo(!LINE!%_FILL%
            )
            endlocal
        )
    )
    > nul move /Y "%_RESULT%.tmp" "%_RESULT%"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```